# How to update a session variable of a specific session

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

So I have a cart system that needs to update the quantity of a specific session variable. Right now if I have a item with the id = 1,

[image: ![enter image description here]

and add another item with an id = 1, it updates the quantity to 2

[image]

, which is fine. But then if I add an item with id = 2,

[image]

and I again add another item with id = 1, it updates the quantity of id = 2 to 2,

[image]

when it should update the quantity of id = 1 to 3

[image]

Here's my code :

```
$exists = false;
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['product_id'] == $part_id) {
        $exists = true;
    }
}
if ($exists == true) {
    $_SESSION["cart"][$key]['quantity']++;
}
else{
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array(
    'product_id' => $part_id,
    'title' => $title,
    'price' => $price,
    'default_img' => $default_img,
    'quantity' => $quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your loop, when you update `$_SESSION["cart"][$key]['quantity']`, `$key` will always be pointing at the last item in `$_SESSION["cart"]`, hence the behaviour you are seeing. You should either do the update in the loop e.g.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['product_id'] == $part_id) {
        $exists = true;
        $_SESSION["cart"][$key]['quantity']++;
    }
}
```

or break from the loop when you find a match so that `$key` is pointing at the correct value:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['product_id'] == $part_id) {
        $exists = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. Didn't realize $key was pointing to the last item, thought it was updating for each item. Thanks again.